# Boost asio socket: how to get IP, port address of connection?

Tags: c++, tcp, ip, boost-asio

I have a TCP server using boost asio. I have accepted a socket connection. How to get IP, Port of machine my server is communicating with?

BTW: Is it possible to get info on what ip that connected server user sees my server4 machine?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get the IP and port like this:

```
std::string sClientIp = socket().remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
unsigned short uiClientPort = socket().remote_endpoint().port();
```

Answer (score 5):

still if you get Bad File Descriptor error in remote_endpoint you can refer to below link.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/accept.html

"Accept a new connection and obtain the endpoint of the peer." part will be helpful to you.

You can use as below

```
tcp::acceptor::endpoint_type end_type;
acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf(), end_type);
std::string sClientIp = end_type.address().to_string();
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/endpoint.html

i don't have experience in it, but it looks like address and port member functions should do the trick

(edit for latest Boost version)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment on the original answer. I just want to mention that there's some problem with the top voted answer: `socket().remote_endpoint()` may throw `boost::system::system_error`. So remember to handle the exception or your program may crash. It took me many hours to debug this problem.